# Check if value from one list is present in specific ID of another list

Tags: c#, linq, class, lambda, generic-list

I have 2 object lists.

1. The first list has:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CAT |
| 2 | DOG |

2. The second list has the below details:

| Name | OBJ ID |
| --- | --- |
| CAT | 500 |
| DOG | 500 |
| CAT | 600 |
| DOG | 600 |
| DOG | 700 |

**Note**: I have a total of 3 OBJ IDS 500,600,700 in list 2

How can I find that CAT from list 2 is missing a value of 700 in it?
Output should only show CAT is missing for 700. As DOG is having all it's values 500,600,700 but CAT is only having 500,600 not 700

```
List<Employee> e1 = new List<Employee>();
e1.Add(new Employee { Name = "CAT" });
e1.Add(new Employee { Name = "DOG" });

List<company> c1 = new List<company>();
c1.Add(new company { objid="1", cname = "CAT", id = "500" });
c1.Add(new company { objid = "2", cname = "DOG", id = "500"});
c1.Add(new company { objid = "3", cname = "CAT", id = "600" });
c1.Add(new company { objid = "4", cname = "DOG", id = "600" });
c1.Add(new company { objid = "5", cname = "DOG", id = "700" });

var QSOuterJoin = from emp in  e1
                  join add in c1
                  on emp.Name equals add.cname
                  into EmployeeNameGroup
                  from address in EmployeeNameGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new  
                        { emp,
                          address };

List<int> uniqlist = new List<int>();
uniqlist.Add(500);
uniqlist.Add(600);
uniqlist.Add(700);

foreach (var i in QSOuterJoin)
{
  foreach (var j in uniqlist)
  {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.address?.id))
    {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} is not {1} {2}", i.emp.Name, i.address?.id, j);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: its unclear what you are asking please share your code of the lsits as well

Comment: Code is added. Please review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ids = c1.Select(x => x.id).Distinct().ToList();
    var result = c1.GroupBy(x => x.cname)
                   .SelectMany(g => ids.Except(g.Select(y => (y.id)))
                                    .Select(x => (Name: g.Key, Id: x)));
```

Comment: Perhaps `Distinct()` would be good to have in `ids`?

Comment: @NetMage yes, agree

Comment: This is only giving me value not the respective ID it is missing for. Eg. Output should show value 700 which is missing for CAT

Comment: @PraneshSankpal Updated the include the ID